# Bibliography style : small caps and bold

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, small-caps

My purpose is to reproduce this type of bibliography :

[image: My desired bibliography]

I identified three major things :

1. This is an `alpha` style bibliography.
2. The cite name **[Luo15]** is in bold.
3. The name of the authors are in small caps.

I managed to solve items 1 and 2 this way :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

%Bibliography Style
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{\textbf{[#1]}}
\makeatother
\bibliographystyle{alpha}

% Command for bold cite in text
\newcommand{\ccite}[1]{\textbf{\cite{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\bibliography{bibliographyName}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}

\end{document}
```

This just to show you I worked a little and that I am not asking this without trying before !

How can I make the author name in small caps to finish the reproduction of the desired bibliography ?

Thank you !

EDIT. The bibliography style I want looks like th `cparalleles` style here : http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/~kjt/software/latex/showbst.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great tool for writing bst files: `makebst` by Patrick Daly. It comes with a standard LaTeX distribution and you call it

```
latex makebst
```

It now asks you a lot of questions interactively and allows you to create a custom bst file for you requirements.

EDIT: When you have created a custom bst file like this, just replace the line

```
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
```

with

```
\bibliographystyle{myalpha} % Insert your choosen name here
```

and it should build smoothly running the usual sequence latex-bibtex-latex-latex.

Comment: It looks good, but I don't know if it is usable with ShareLatex. I'll see. Still I think I missed a one line command to solve my problem ^^

Comment: @M.LTA Unfortunately, I don't think it is a one-liner. It is, of course, possible to copy alpha.bst to myalpha.bst and edit it; but the drawback is that you must acquaint yourself to yet another programming language of an unusual type.

Comment: I am ready to try with `makebst` : on my computer, windows produces a .mst just fine, but I don't know how to use it with Sharelatex (which I use a lot), do you know how to do it ?

Comment: Ok so I uploaded the file .bst and then I called `\bibliographystyle{mybibliography}`  and it works !
Another question : I am french and I want real french guillemets in the bibliography. Is there a method to allow `makebst` to use the french babel package and the `\og \fg{}` commands ?

Comment: @M.LTA: BibTeX is completely agnostic of `babel` or other language packages and will happily write any TeX command (like `\og \fg{}` into your bibliography. Your bibliography will than only compile with `babel` loaded which is fine since you know wat you are doing.